# Check if react native iOS application has been installed from the AppStore

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there a way to check if an iOS app, built with React Native, has been installed from the AppStore?

My scenario is that I would like to only turn Google Analtyics on if installed from the AppStore and not HockeyApp.

Comment: For these functionalities is that the targets were created, to maintain several enviroments. Example: (staging, prod). Read about targets in xcode

Comment: How do SDK's like buddybuild and hockeyapp etc work then? They disable features in my build for the AppStore without changing targets.